# How to check visibility of object using qtp

Tags: html, qtp

i have a requirement to verify that for a selected value in a drop down list in a webpage, one text box in the same page gets invisible or not. But when i checked the run time properties (disabled and invisible) of the textbox, in both cases i.e. when visible in the page and when not visible in the page.. both the properties are coming out to be same in both cases. What else i can do to verify the same. I am using qtp 11.0

Comment: What code did you use? What does the HTML look like?

Comment: Read this: http://www.knowledgeinbox.com/articles/qtp/issues/exist-returns-true-even-when-the-object-does-not-exists/

Answer (score 0):

You could try using readonly property of text field.

Thanks.